# Cordova InAppBrowser how can i get full download support

Tags: javascript, android, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins

Currently I’m working on a app with Cordova for Android and IOS. This app opens a website in the in app browser of Cordova. Now I’m trying to get full download support for this website. Direct download links aren’t really a problem like a .pdf but some download links are just JavaScript posts to a download manager on the server. Currently the InAppBrowser doesn’t do anything with it and because it isn’t a link I can’t attach an event. 
Does anyone have a idea how I could solve this problem?

I’m currently using the [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/releases) version 1.7.0 with Cordova 7.0.1